# I can not define a cbr agent in NS2 2.35

Tags: ns2

I try to write some prepared scripts to learn ns2 but I face a problem. this is a code I find it somewhere:

```
set ns [new Simulator]
set nf [open out.nam w]
$ns namtrace-all $nf
proc finish {} {
global ns nf
$ns flush-trace
close $nf
exec nam out.nam &
exit 0
}

set n0 [$ns node]
set n1 [$ns node]
$ns duplex-link $n0 $n1 1Mb 10ms DropTail

set udp0 [new Agent/UDP]
$ns attach-agent $n0 $udp0
set null0 [new Agent/Null]
$ns attach-agent $n1 $null0

set cbr0 [new Application/Traffic/CBR]
cbr0 set packetSize_ 500
cbr0 set interval_ 0.005
cbr0 attach-agent $udp0

$ns connect $udp $null0

$ns at 1.0 "$cbr0 start"
$ns at 4.5 "$cbr0 stop"

$ns at 5.0 "finish"

$ns run
```

after I run the script I see this error:

```
invalid command name "cbr0"
while executing
"cbr0 set packetSize_ 500"
(file "ex2.tcl" line 23)
```

since I just copy these from a book I don't think I should make mistake and problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

> set cbr0 [new Application/Traffic/CBR]

Is defined OK with `set cbr0 [new Application/Traffic/CBR]`

When defined, cbr0 must be used as `$cbr0`, like you do with `ns` / `$ns` :

```
$cbr0 set packetSize_ 500
$cbr0 set interval_ 0.005
$cbr0 attach-agent $udp0
```

Other error : udp0 is defined, but not used :

> $ns connect $udp $null0

Must be :

```
$ns connect $udp0 $null0
```

Basic examples https://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/tutorial/ → example1
https://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/tutorial/nsscript1.html → https://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/tutorial/nsscript2.html , etc.